How to access content of angular cdk overlay?
<input  autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" type="text" class="input">
<ng-template
  cdkConnectedOverlay
  [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="origin"
  [cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="isOpen"
  [cdkConnectedOverlayOffsetY]="12"
  cdkConnectedOverlayHasBackdrop
  cdkConnectedOverlayBackdropClass="cdk-overlay-transparent-backdrop"
  (backdropClick)="close()"
  (detach)="close()"
>
<div class="suggestions-container" @dropDown (@dropDown.done)="onPanelAnimationDone($event)">
<app-option  #options  *ngFor="let item of items " [item]="item"></app-option>
  </div>
</ng-template>

 @ViewChildren('options') public options!: QueryList<OptionComponent<T>>;
 @Input() items: any;

 @HostListener('click')
  open() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.options.changes.pipe(
        startWith<QueryList<OptionComponent<T>>>(this.options),
        tap(() => this.highlightSelectedOptions()),
        switchMap(options => merge(...options.map((o: OptionComponent<T>) => o.selected))),
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
      ).subscribe(selectedOption => {
        this.handleSelection(selectedOption)
      });
    })
    this.isOpen = true;
  }

I am completely new to using the Angular CDK Overlay module. I want to create a dynamic searchable select component, and I need to have access to the content of the overlay in my host component.
The only solution I have reached is inside the open method, but I think there might be a better solution.
I would appreciate your help in this regard. I need to have access to options as a QueryList, but the content of the QueryList is empty inside ngAfterViewInit, and only when the overlay is opened does it return the content of the QueryList.

You can make your code very simpler, just do not even worry about the html content, instead just add a property called selected on the array itself, so you will always know what is selected and unselected without relying on the html since the content gets created and destroyed using ngIf, if you do not want to modify the original array, create a new array which stores the selected values
